# Assembly Language, moving the picture across the screen

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm new to Assembly Language, very complex language. Reading this book and I'm trying to move the picture across the screen with a delay of 300. Here's what the program from the book says. "Move the picture across the screen from 10,10 to 20,10 with a delay of 300"

I'm wondering how to add this and hopefully get the picture moving across the screen, book doesn't really explain that good for my understanding.

Here's the program I have made.

```
   TITLE  call demos          (calldemoline.asm)
;  
; Last update:Dec 1, 2015   
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
 .data
    deltax byte ?
    number byte ?
    symbol byte ?
    y1 byte 10
.code    
 main proc
       call clrscr
      mov ecx,7
     mov eax,ecx
     add eax,ecx
     inc eax   ;ecx+1
     mov number,al

     picture:
         movzx eax,number
        mov deltax, cl          
        mov al,'-'
        mov symbol,al
        call drawline
        mov al,number
        sub al,cl
        sub al,cl
        mov deltax,al
        mov al,'x'
        mov symbol,al
        call drawline
        movzx eax,number
        mov deltax, cl          
        mov al,'-'
        mov symbol,al
        call drawline
        call crlf
     loop picture
      exit
main ENDP
 drawline proc
     push ecx
  movzx ecx, deltax
        mov al,symbol
     draw:
           call writechar
       loop draw
      pop ecx
     ret
    drawline endp
END main
```

Comment: I made a mistake on that one.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1) How to place the picture?
2) How to move it?

1) Your drawing action is actually a sequence of `call writechar` at the current position of the cursor. With `call clrscr` and `call crlf` you move the cursor to the left boarder. To move the cursor to another position the Irvine library provides the function [`Gotoxy`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fgotoxy.htm).

Try it:

```
...
mov dh, 0                   ; Row = 0
picture:

    mov dl, 10              ; Col = 10
    call Gotoxy

    ... (no change)

    ; call crlf
    inc dh                  ; Instead of call crlf
loop picture
...
```

2) To move the picture you have to blank out the old picture before painting the new picture. Clearing is in your case easy: Instead of writing '-' and 'x' just write a space. I have just doubled the drawing block and changed the characters:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    deltax byte ?
    number byte ?
    symbol byte ?
    y1 byte 10

    col BYTE 9              ; Column of the first clearing action
    row BYTE 0

.code
main PROC
    call clrscr

    mov ecx,7
    mov eax,ecx
    add eax,ecx
    inc eax   ;ecx+1
    mov number,al

    L1:
    call clear_picture
    inc col                 ; Next column
    call draw_picture
    mov eax, 300
    call Delay
    cmp col, 20             ; Was picture drawed at column 20?
    jne L1                  ; No, once one

    L2:
    exit
main ENDP

draw_picture PROC USES ECX
    movzx eax, row              ; Preserve row
    push eax

    picture:
    mov dl, col
    mov dh, row
    call Gotoxy

    movzx eax,number
    mov deltax, cl
    mov al,'-'
    mov symbol,al
    call drawline

    mov al,number
    sub al,cl
    sub al,cl
    mov deltax,al
    mov al,'x'
    mov symbol,al
    call drawline

    movzx eax,number
    mov deltax, cl
    mov al,'-'
    mov symbol,al
    call drawline

    inc row                     ; Instead of call crlf
    loop picture

    pop eax                     ; Restore row
    mov row, al
    ret
draw_picture ENDP

clear_picture PROC USES ECX
    movzx eax, row              ; Preserve row
    push eax

    picture:
    mov dl, col
    mov dh, row
    call Gotoxy

    movzx eax,number
    mov deltax, cl
    mov al,' '
    mov symbol,al
    call drawline

    mov al,number
    sub al,cl
    sub al,cl
    mov deltax,al
    mov al,' '
    mov symbol,al
    call drawline

    movzx eax,number
    mov deltax, cl
    mov al,' '
    mov symbol,al
    call drawline

    inc row                     ; Instead of call crlf
    loop picture

    pop eax                     ; Restore row
    mov row, al
    ret
clear_picture ENDP

drawline PROC
    push ecx
    movzx ecx, deltax
    mov al,symbol

    draw:
    call writechar
    loop draw

    pop ecx
    ret
drawline ENDP

END main
```